# PowerShell get-acl List folder contents vs ReadAndExecute

Tags: powershell, permissions, ntfs

This is a simple question yet I could not find an answer on Google or here yet:

By using PowerShell or cmd (no third party stuff), how can I retrieve folder permissions in a way that allows me to differ between "List Folder Contents" and "ReadAndExecute"?

Right now when I execute Get-Acl on a folder, it returns the same permission level when a group grants only list access or read and execute. If I right click and go to Security tab, one group has "List folder contents" checked and another has "Read & Execute" checked, but both return "ReadAndExecute" with Get-Acl.

Pictures below:

[image: group 1]

[image: group 2]

Powershell just returns "ReadAndExecute" for both:

FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize

AccessControlType : Allow

IdentityReference : group1

IsInherited       : False

InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit

PropagationFlags  : None

---

FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize

AccessControlType : Allow

IdentityReference : group2

IsInherited       : False

InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit

PropagationFlags  : None

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a viable solution to this by myself after a while.

Even though PowerShell (or CMD or C#) always returns "ReadAndExecute" for both ListDirectory or actual ReadAndExecute permissions, the "InheritanceFlag" will always be "ContainerInherit" only when the permission is "ListDirectory". As such, checking this flag, you may find out which group grants only list permissions instead of read and execute.

I have implemented this check in PowerShell, which is working for all test cases so far:

```
foreach($access in (Get-Acl 'C:\test').Access) {
    $filerights = $access.FileSystemRights.ToString();
    $inheritanceFlg = $access.InheritanceFlags.ToString();
    if($inheritanceFlg -eq 'ContainerInherit') {
        $filerights = $filerights.replace('ReadAndExecute','ListDirectory');
    }
    $output = $access.IdentityReference.ToString() + ';' + $filerights;
    $output
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your answer is great but have just a little mistake. You're getting the wrong parameter at $inheritanceFlags variable at line 3. The below is correct:

```
foreach($access in (Get-Acl 'C:\Test').Access) {
    $filerights = $access.FileSystemRights.ToString();
    $inheritanceFlg = $access.InheritanceFlags.ToString();
    if($inheritanceFlg -eq 'ContainerInherit') {
        $filerights = $filerights.replace('ReadAndExecute','ListDirectory');
    }
    $output = $access.IdentityReference.ToString() + ';' + $filerights;
    $output
}
```

Comment: That was a typo I only noticed later and forgot to correct here, thanks

Comment: This should be a comment on the original posters post, not duplicating bar a few characters another's answer. Clutters the simple Q&C format of SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

```
(get-Acl 'C:\Temp').Access
```

returns collection of `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule` objects.

It has a `FileSystemRights` property of type `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights`. This is an enumeration and it can be checked for individual rights. For example (checking first access rule below):

```
((Get-Acl 'C:\Temp').Access[0].FileSystemRights -band
[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::ExecuteFile) -eq   
[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::ExecuteFile
```

ListDirectory, ExecuteFile, Read is what you may check to catch the difference in permissions.

More info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am using Get-Acl. Here's what it returns on a folder with 2 groups, one of which is List folder contents access only:FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : group1
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : group2
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit
PropagationFlags  : None