# PowerShell command Get-Acl.Access shows different permissions than Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am working on listing out the users and groups who have access to a shared folder on our networking using PowerShell and Active directory but I am getting different results. When I run the command `(Get-Acl -Path "D:\ADMIN_FOLDER").Access` I see a security group called `EVERYONE` has the `ReadAndExecute` and when I check the folder permissions using Active Directory it shows the `EVERYONE` group only has the `List folder contents` permission. I am wondering why PowerShell and AD show different results? Is there a different PowerShell command I need to get? Or do I have to rely on AD for accurate folder level permissions?

Comment: maybe this topic will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414438/powershell-get-acl-list-folder-contents-vs-readandexecute